# Trajectory of charged particle entering experiencing unequal electric force and magnetic force

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge

This is a question raised when I was having Physics lesson (high school, not university), we were studying the circular motion of $QvB = {\frac {mv^2}{r}}$ and also  straight line path $QvB = QE$. We were curious about what will happen when the charged particle experiences unequal magnetic force and electric force.

This is my attempt on this problem (just basic calculus since we don’t touch calculus in Physics)
[image]

And I plotted the displacement-time graph of the particle on Desmos:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/skhvjsjuhh

This graph works when $B=0$ or $v={\frac {E}{B}}$, but does not show that it goes in circular motion when $E=0$ (probably expect sine/cosine graphs?)

I think there must be an error in my calculations, any help to solve my problem would be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your handwriting, it is very nice and neat. And you showed a lot of work. Technically, PSE is not for homework and checking of homework, but with this much effort and this nice, it really gives us an incentive to try and help.

Now, it seems you were plotting using Cartesian coördinates. Then you should get the initial equation in terms of Cartesian coördinates, i.e. get rid of angles.

Or you could express everything in terms of polar coördinates. This might be too difficult for you right now.

I suppose plotting the motion in space is also difficult.

Comment: I believe that what I got is the Cartesian coordinates. In the final expression, I got the tan(theta) in terms of the supposedly given variables, which means I had got rid of the angles already. And the expression is just substituted into the expression on the next step (done by graphing calculator.

Comment: For the issue of homework stuff: I would like to clarify that this is actually not an homework. It is just a question (out of scope in my level) that pops up from curiosity, so I would like to discuss with people who has higher degrees than me. And finally, thanks for appreciating my handwriting.

Comment: No, if you did it purely in Cartesian coördinates, you would get rid of cosines, sines, tangents, and have functions of x and y that implement cosines and sines. e.g. cosine $= x / \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and so forth. Note also that I think your initial equations are wrong. The initial magnetic force should be upwards for positive Q if your initial velocity is rightwards.

Comment: I think you got some misunderstanding in my calculations, the tangent expression at the final line is to be substituted into $v_{parallel}$ and $v_{perpendicular}$, with this we can get rid of the thetas. The initial conditions should be correct when theta = 0 at time = 0s

Comment: No, it is clear that this is part of where there is a problem. Whatever is parallel and perpendicular, and theta, changes as you move! If you wish to make progress in your problem, the fastest way is to try and compute purely in Cartesian coördinates. Or you have to fix your theta.